# Why create datastore in GeoServer REST API can not create database on PostgreSQL also?

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I am going to create datastore (PostGIS type) in a workspace by GeoServer REST API. Moreover I want it create database with exact datastore name on PostgreSQL simultaneously. Therefore I add  `<entry key="create database">true</entry>` to my `datastore.xml` file (based on GeoServer REST API). It can create datastore in workspace without any error. However it cannot create database same datastore name on PostgreSQL! It seems it did incomplete! This is because if I login to GeoServer web administrator interface when I click store name. I can see form is completed! And everything is checked already but it didn't save. If I press save button it will finish its task completely. And it can create database on PostgreSQL.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataStore>
    <name>G0BUXtNQiQ</name>
    <type>PostGIS</type>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <workspace>
      <name>G0BUXtNQiQ</name>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/G0BUXtNQiQ.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </workspace>
    <connectionParameters>
      <entry key="port">5432</entry>
      <entry key="user">postgres</entry>
      <entry key="passwd">postgres</entry>
      <entry key="dbtype">postgis</entry>
      <entry key="host">localhost</entry>
      <entry key="database">G0BUXtNQiQ</entry>
      <entry key="schema">public</entry>
      <entry key="create database">true</entry>
    </connectionParameters>
    <__default>false</__default>
  </dataStore>
```

[image]
[image]

This is log file:

> 2020-09-07 17:39:46,990 WARN [geofence.cache] -
> org.geoserver.geofence.cache.CachedRuleReader$NoAuthException: Can't
> auth user [admin] 2020-09-07 17:39:47,045 INFO
> [auth.GeoFenceAuthenticationProvider] - User admin NOT authenticated
> 2020-09-07 17:39:49,127 WARN [geofence.cache] -
> org.geoserver.geofence.cache.CachedRuleReader$NoAuthException: Can't
> auth user [admin] 2020-09-07 17:39:49,287 WARN [geoserver.security] -
> Failed login, user admin from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2020-09-07 17:39:49,287
> INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying
> login for 1842ms 2020-09-07 17:39:51,695 INFO [geoserver.security] -
> Strong cryptography is available

SYSINFO: GeoServer 2.17.2,
PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: Please share the logs generated by GeoServer during that REST call.

Comment: I used axios, my username and password was correct I don't know why in log I got warning due to auth admin